# Как в Java получить класс, который выполнил вызов текущего класса?

Tags: java, классы

У меня есть класс `CfgMgr`, который часто вызывают другие классы в программе. Как в `CfgMgr` узнать, какой класс вызвал его в данный момент?

Answer (score 2):

Через стрек трейс. Самый простой и надежный метод - создать объект типа `Exception`.

Например есть такой вызывающий класс:

```java
package so;

public class Caller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Callee().call();
    }

}
```

Теперь вызываемый класс мог бы реализовать такую логику:

```java
package so;

public class Callee {

    public void call(){
        System.out.println("I am called from: " + new Exception().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName());
    }
}
```

Результатом запуска стало бы:

```
I am called from: so.Caller
```

Comment: Екцепшн бросать мягко говоря накладно, достаточно вызвать `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

Comment: Можно и так, но там есть нюанс со стеком. Он начинается не в методе вызова.

Comment: @Serodv поддерживаю Алексея. писал свою утилиту для логов, чтобы показывало место где написано лог. баловался и с Thread и с Exception. Exception - лучше. но можно не прям выкидвать ошибку через throw, а просто создать объект класса ошибки и в ее стактрейс залезть.

Comment: @Wlad точно, спасибо! Я почему-то думал что стек трейс именно в момент выбрасывания инциализируется в ексепшене. Поправил ответ.